# How can I specify method and path for calling lambda function from step function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I'd like to call lambda function using a state machine with passing `path` and `method` (as in usual HTTP sense). Current serverless template to achieve that is the following:

```
functions:
  myfunction:
    handler: bin/myfunction
    events:
      - http:
          path: setup
          method: POST

stepFunctions:
  validate: true
  stateMachines:
    myMachine:
      name: myMachine
      definition:
        StartAt: Setup
        States:
          Setup:
            Type: Task
            Resource:
              Fn::GetAtt: [myfunction, Arn]
            Parameters:
              InvocationType: Event
              Payload:
                path: "/setup"
                httpMethod: "POST"
                body: ""
            End: true
```

However, the actual call that arrives to `myfunction` is a `GET` request with path `/`. Fields that I used as a payload are from `lambda:InvokeFunction` API where one can set `body`, `path` and `httpMethod` as a json in `Payload` property of `lambda.InvokeInput` and get everything called correctly.

How to replicate the same with my example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`path` and `httpMethod` are for invoking an **API Gateway** route, not a **Lambda function**.

A [Lambda function invocation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html) (mostly) takes a function name, invocation type & a payload.

If you must go via API Gateway, take a look at the official ['Call API Gateway with Step Functions'](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-api-gateway.html) guide on how to do this otherwise just invoke your Lambda manually.